# how to make iframe banner

Tags: java, html, banner

Hello 
I tried to put ad banner on my website but it doesnt work (i have some problem with javascript) but iframes works so I will like to make a iframe from it (<iframe></iframe>).
How i can do it ?
Here is the code :

```html
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="//www.bitcoadz.io/display/items.php?5831&1627&468&60&1"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

iframe sample

```
$('<iframe>', {
src: 'http://google.com',
id:  'myFrame',
frameborder: 0,
scrolling: 'no'
}).appendTo('.accordion');
```

or

```
$('<iframe id="someId"/>').appendTo('#someDiv')
                      .contents().find('body').append(response);
```

`someDiv` is id where you want to append iframe. `response` is what you want to append in iframe.